# Cache invalidation for generic repositories

Tags: artifactory

We set up and Artifactory instance with a generic repo that proxies https://nodejs.org/dist/.

The problem is that the upstream repo has files that change over time. I checked the available documentation but haven't found pointers to whether is it possible to set up some cache invalidation policy that would allow us to purge the stale content from the cached files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running with Artifactory Pro, you can develop your own cache invalidation mechanism using a User Plugin. Have a look [at this plugin](https://github.com/JFrogDev/artifactory-user-plugins/blob/master/metadata/expirePackagesMetadata/expirePackagesMetadata.groovy) as an example.

The idea is to mark a resource as "expired" just before Artifactory processes the download request, making Artifactory replace the cached version with the upstream version. Plugins such as this one are usually used to replace metadata files in repo types that aren't officially supported (CRAN, for example), but you can use it to expire any generic file. This functionality is documented as part of the beforeDownloadRequest comment block on our [User Plugins Wiki](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/User+Plugins).

Comment: I guess this is not a very special requirement. Let's hope it will be builr into the product in the near future.